# A* Algorithm Quickest Time

Tags: java, algorithm, path, shortest-path, a-star

I've implemented the A* Algorithm to give the shortest distance route, however I'm trying to alter that so it will calculate the quickest route. 
Using this pseudocode:

```
function A*(start,goal)
    closedset := the empty set    // The set of nodes already evaluated.
    openset := {start}    // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node
    came_from := the empty map    // The map of navigated nodes.

    g_score[start] := 0    // Cost from start along best known path.
    // Estimated total cost from start to goal through y.
    f_score[start] := g_score[start] + heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

    while openset is not empty
        current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
        if current = goal
            return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)

        remove current from openset
        add current to closedset
        for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
            if neighbor in closedset
                continue
            tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)

            if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor] 
                came_from[neighbor] := current
                g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
                f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
                if neighbor not in openset
                    add neighbor to openset

    return failure
```

I thought that the easiest way to calculate the quickest route would be to divide the distance between current and neighbour by the speed limit of that road: tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + (dist_between(current,neighbor)/neighbor.speedlimit)
However this doesn't give the correct result in my algorithm.

Can anyone possibly point me in the right direction as to how to do this efficiently?

Here is my current code: http://pastebin.com/QWi6AwF9

Quickest route as in, one that takes the least time to reach the destination from the start location.

My heuristic function is this

```
private double heuristic(Vertex goal, Vertex next) 
    {
        return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((goal.x - next.x), 2) + Math.pow((goal.y - next.y), 2)));
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: If you attached your current solution implemented in Java, others would be able to run it and help you much easier.

Comment: I was reluctant to do so, as this is an assignment and I know other students in my class use this website; therefore it'd be easy for them to see my code. However I've uploaded it to pastebin and it has an expiry time.

Comment: Your approach seems correct (if the speed limit is a positive number). What is not correct about the result it gives?

Comment: If I calculate the same route asking for the shortest distance, the time of that route is a lot shorter than the time given when asking for the quickest time. It seems to explore a very little amount of nodes; comparing the same route but shortest distance, it explores about 20x less.

Comment: The one thing that looks odd is that you're taking the speed limit as an attribute of a (neightbour) node, while in reality it would be an attribute of the edge from the current node to the neighbour node. Maybe that is part of the problem.

Comment: The road I use (currentRoad) links the current location (tempVertex) with the neighbour node(vertexNeighbour). Isn't that the correct way?

Comment: Could you please add a precise definition of what the "quickest" root means exactly and what heuristic function is used?

Comment: I've added it into the original post :) Is that more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heuristic function must be admissible(that is, it should never overestimate the distance to the goal). Once you start dividing the length of an edge by `speedlimit`, the real distance to the goal might be less than the Euclidean distance to it(if `speedlimit > 1`). It breaks the algorithm. How to fix it? For example, you can use `dist / MAX_SPEED_LIMIT`  as a heursitic function instead.

Comment: Ah thank you, I assume that would be the distance between the current node and the goal, divided by the max speed limit of all the edges?